# Rename target files while using zip command

Tags: linux, unix, zip

I'm using the `zip` command to zip files, such as `zip -r - file1 file2 file3`

We want to rename these files however, before they are zipped.

Does anyone know if there's a way to pipe this or somehow rename the files that are being added to the zip?

Comment: Consider editing your question to show how you intend to rename a group of files without issuing unique cmds like `mv file1 fileA` before using zip OR performing similar  rename operation inside the zip archive. Put another way, edit your question to show how you would like this to work, given 3 files, and 1 zip archive. Good luck.

Comment: Basically, I just want to rename files that are going into the zip, so I don't want to create new files or rename the actual files themselves, only rename them going into the zip file.  Does that make sense?

Comment: sorry, I don't think it's possible unless you invent a whole new zip wrapper application that can handle your requirement. Either you rename the files before you put them in the archive, OR you rename them after they're in the archive  My point is, given your example `zip -r - file1 file2 file3` what is there to indicate that file1 is the old filename and file2 is the rename target AND how you expect that to work OR where do you pass in the mapping of oldFile=newFile? Good luck.

Comment: You can create a bunch of symbolic links to the files that you want to put into the zip file rather than renaming them, and create the .zip with those files, which is the trivial way to accomplish this

Answer (score 5):

Command `zipnote`:

```
echo -e "@ myOldFileName.txt\n@=myNewFileName.txt" | zipnote -w myzip.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing customized name to the outcoming xyz.zip folder is possible.
but renaming the input file should be done before it takes input for processing ZIP action.

Following are the possible ways that will create archivefile1.zip file

```
zip -r archivefile1 .
zip -r archivefile1 .* *
zip -r archivefile1 .*
```